# Error al generar nombre seguro ensamblado. Assembly generation failed -- 'S22.Imap' referenced assembly does not have a strong name

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget

Saludos,
tengo un problema de una dll que fue descargada desde visual Studio 2010, en Nuget Packages.
Despues de crear la firma del ensamblado, me sale el siguiente error:

**Assembly generation failed -- 'S22.Imap' referenced assembly does not have a strong name.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El hecho de crear la firma del ensamblado, me es necesario realizarla, porque debo crear una dll final, con el objetivo de ser utilizada en fox pro.
Quizas la solución está en darle un nombre seguro a la dll S22.Imap, que fue descargada desde el Nuget packaget. Y si fuera así, como?¿o cual sería la solución?
desde ya, gracias por la atención.

Comment: Mira esta respuesta en [MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f0dbab83-f912-4db9-adf2-f43ff74e4e73/assembly-generation-failed-referenced-assembly-xyz-does-not-have-a-strong-name?forum=csharpgeneral). Cuando tuve ese problema era porque mi ensamblado no estaba firmado y con contraseña. Esto antes de incluirlo "en mi caso" en el GAC "Global Assembly Cache".

Comment: si @Mauricio Arias Olave, pero la dll que me da problema es S22.Imap( descargada de Nuget package), y quiero crear una dll leeCorreo que incluya la del problema. No tengo como firma la dll S22.Imap, ya que fue descargada de visual, es solo dll, no sabria como hacerlo